# React Jest how to test if a span contains some certain text from mount snapshot?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-test-renderer

I am testing a component that does not have any id for me to be able to select from Jest, my mounted component snapshot will be like

```
<div id='divHeader'>
    <h2
      className=""
      style={Object {}}
    >
      <span
        className=""
        style={Object {}}
      >
        This is an English text
      </span>
    </h2>
</div>
```

So is there any way for me to verify that the text inside my span from the snapshot would contain the world `English`, something like

```
widget = mount(<MyComponent {...defaultProp} />);
// widget.find('span').text.contains('English')   
// widget.find('[id="divHeader"]').h2.span.text.contains('English')
```

I am having some trouble in the `find` here where I know it can find the element by id, but unfortunately I cannot assign any id to my span, and even I can find my div by id, I cannot select its children element like div->h2->span...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find returns a `ReactWrapper` like mount, so you can chain find calls.

For example, something like this.

```
widget.find('[id="divHeader"]').find('h2').find('span').text().contains('English')
```

Comment: Awesome! Somehow the `text` does not work for me, I have to use `....find('span').props().children` which gives me the inner html text, is that expected? the `find('span')` will return the `ReactWrapper` which I don't know what's inside when I do the `console.log(...find('span'))`

Comment: ah text is a function not a prop value. .text(). find returns a ReactWapper not a domnode.

Comment: also debug is helpful. console.log(wrap.find(...).debug())

Answer (score 0):

We can test using Jest and Enzyme:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

const widget = shallow(<MyComponent {...defaultProp} />);

expect(widget.find('#divHeader').find('h2').find('span').text().contains('This is an English text')).toBe(true);
```

Or else you can directly find by Selector for that particular HTML element and test it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent {...defaultProp} />);
expect(wrapper.find('span').text()).toContain('English');
```